# Mobile + Rails, Firebase vs Couchbase

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, firebase, couchbase, nosql

I am currently involved in a project where we need to use a NoSQL database to store data that is to be used and modified on both a Ruby on Rails and a native Android application. We need some kind of user authentication where users have different permissions to modify different kinds of data. Automated syncing from the app to the server is a must, but will only be available once every couple of weeks. So the app will be primarily used offline. I am looking at either Firebase or Couchbase but I am open to others.
My question is what are the pros and cons of using Firebase and Couchbase? What would you recommend for my situation?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score -2):

this is Jessica from the PM team at Couchbase. I'm biased, of course, in this opinion but Couchbase offers a lot of granular access control, a variety of syncing options including automatic sync for opportunistic sync scenarios, and was made with the very specific idea to be offline-ready. The embedded database that is part of Couchbase's solution for on-device storage can be standalone or it can replicate back to a remote backend, and we have thought out the various conflict management requirements needed to ensure data is consistent across both your local and remote systems. Couchbase fulfills every one of the requirements you have thus far posted, but would be happy to discuss more if you would like. Feel free to reach out to me at jessica [at] couchbase [dot] com.